# HTML Email Signature - Images side by side with NO SPACE between

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to create a HTML Email signature where I place 2 images side by side.

Here is the html code I am using:
https://codepen.io/klodoma/pen/mdeQYrB

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0;        
    }
    img { display: block;}
    .row {
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: flex;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DyCPXxdQ/hair-left.png" alt="Left Image"/>
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Mpvbb1dC/hair-right.png" alt="Right Image"/>
</div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DyCPXxdQ/hair-left.png" alt="Left Image"/></td>
        <td><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Mpvbb1dC/hair-right.png" alt="Right Image"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried:

- creating a DIV
- creating a TABLE

In Html both look very good, but when I paste this code in an email client (Outlook for example) there are some problems.

If the width of the emails page is not enough, then the div shifts the images(even though word-wrap is disabled). 
In the table version there is a vertical space I couldn't get rid of.

Any ideas to solve this? I don't care which solution will work, divs or tables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few aspects here:

Outlook only reads the height and width numerical values (and if they're outside of the style tag too I think). Here you can see below I've added redundancy to my approach.

```
<img src="https://imageurl....." alt="alt-text" height="48" width="48" style="display: block; width: 48px; height: 48px;" />
```

You may also find it helpful to set the width of your initial table at the same point where you have applied the margin and padding resets.

To remove any unwanted vertical space you should also reset the padding to 0 in the `<td>` elements I believe.